# Why do some openssl subcommands take a -config option and others do not?

Tags: openssl

For instance, req does but x509 does not.

Also I read about the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable. Does that affect the x509 subcommand at all?

Answer (score 1):

Originally the config file was only needed, and specifiable explicitly, for `req` and `ca` because of the relatively complicated parameters needed for cert request and issuance. `ts` added in 1.0.0 did the same, and `srp` added in 1.0.2 (but undocumented) does so for no reason obvious to me, maybe just fashion. `x509` originally was about displaying data, which mostly doesn't need config (see below); some minimal **CA-like features** have been added over time, and (only) they use a file in the config format for extensions; this is identified by `-extfile` and **must be explicit**.

However, since about 0.9.8 (further back than I can conveniently check), there has been a concept of **automatic configuration** for commandline subcommands and also applications using libcrypto, even those that don't have operation-specific or program-specific config items. This is described in the man page config(5) on your Unixy system with OpenSSL properly installed, or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/config.html) and is affected by envvar `OPENSSL_CONF`.

It started with configuring **custom OIDs which could well apply** to `x509`, **and ENGINE settings** which might if you use a hardware key (to sign) or GOST keys (at all). Defaulting FIPS mode (in applications not coded for it) was added mid-1.0.1, and settings (or defaults) for SSL/TLS in 1.1.0.